# How to use 2 UITableView in a UIViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

Plz guide that how can i use 2 UItableView(or more) in a UIViewController & manage their
numberOfRowsInSection,......& other methods.
Any ideas for that??

Comment: This is a UITableView delegate problem, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that your actual problem lies in assigning the same object as UITableViewDelegate:

[UITableViewDelegete](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods pass the UITableView instance to it. You just need to filter out which tableview you need to operate on. For example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == yourFirstTableView) {
        // <do whatever on first table view>...
    } else if (tableView == yourSecondTableView) {
        // <do whatever on second table view>...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// tableView parameter is the tableView for which the delegate method is called
// u can compare this with your table view references
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == myTableView1) {
        // return data for myTableView1
    } else if (tableView == myTableView2) {
        // return data for myTableView2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(tableView1){
    if(section==0)
        return 1; /*  1 row for section 0 in the first table.  */
    if(section==1)
        return 2; /*  2 rows for section 1 in the first table.  */
}

if(tableView2){
    if(section==0)
        return 3; /*  3 row for section 0 in the second table.  */
    if(section==1)
        return 2; /*  2 rows for section 1 in the second table.  */
}
```

Comment: your if condition will always get succeeded!

Answer (score 0):

why are you going to use two tableviews in UIviewcontroller?.It is possible,set tag to each of the tableview you are  adding.u can check these tags in delegate methods and do changes.

Answer (score 0):

use tag..
for eg use table view1 as tag=0
and use table view2 as tag