# How to add multiple tables in UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Any one please tell me how to add two tables in uiview controller?
I created a class object in `rootviewController` as

```
mainDataViewController=[[MainDataViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

And in `mainDataviewController` taken as `UITableviewController`

```
@interface MainDataViewController : UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

Now, I Want to add three tables in `mainDataViewController`.

Please give me some idea for solving this.

Answer (score 2):

follow these steps.

1)Create a tableViewController with xib.
2)Create only two other xib's as given screenshots below:--

[image]
3)Drag uitableView from object window.

[image]

4)Change its class to TableViewController's class you have firstly created.

5)Connect file owner's view delegate to tableView.

6) And use code as ------

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    MYViewController *FirstTableController=[[MYViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MYViewController" bundle:nil];
    MYViewController *secondTableController=[[MYViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MYSecondController" bundle:nil];
    MYViewController *thirdTableController=[[MYViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MYThird" bundle:nil];



    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

[image]

**Or**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MYViewController : UITableViewController
{
   IBOutlet UITableView *f_table,*s_table,*t_table; //outlets for different tableViews in xib.
}

@end
```

[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view=f_table; // when working with first table.

    self.view=s_table; //working with second table.

    self.view=t_table; //working with third table.
}
```

Comment: It is ok for in a view controller.if viewController is initialized as tableview controller.Please check my question code.Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not searched well.
 Please have a look at this.
[How to use 2 UITableView in a UIViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568256/how-to-use-2-uitableview-in-a-uiviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

1) First add tableview on your viewController xib file

[image]

2) declare variables for your tableviews

[image]

3) synthesize properthies

[image]

4) add outlets to your propethies

[image]

Now you can use them...