# Two array and Two UITableview same viewcontroller on Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have a problem in xcode. I want to two array and  two tableview same view controller. My tableviews tags 1001 and 2002. I call web service and make my arrays successfully. I run it and only table1 (tag 1001) is showing value. 2002 nil. My Code is :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (tableView.tag == 1001)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    else
    {
        return 1;
    }

}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ 

       if(tableView.tag==1001)
    {
        NSLog(@"self.Data count: %lu", (unsigned long)[menuData count]);
        return [menuData count];
    }

    else
    NSLog(@"self.İçkiler: %lu", (unsigned long)[icecekData count]);
    return [icecekData count];


}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    int indicator = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;



    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }



NSString * cellValue;


if (tableView.tag==1001)
{

    veriler=[menuData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSLog(@"Name  : %@ ", veriler.menuadi);
    cellValue= veriler.menuadi;

}
if (tableView.tag==2002)

{

    veriler=[icecekData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSLog(@"Name  : %@ ", veriler.icecek);
    cellValue= veriler.icecek;

}




cell.textLabel.text=cellValue;
cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return cell;



}
```

What is  wrong in my code.  Can u help me please.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to call `reloadData` method for both tableViews?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use 2 UITableView in a UIViewController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568256/how-to-use-2-uitableview-in-a-uiviewcontroller)

Comment: Check your numberOfRowsInSection, your else part in numberOfRowsInSection method need to be in block.

Comment: No, İ didnt use `reloadData` . Where can i use ? @MartinPilch

Comment: show your error log.

Comment: No Error  : 2014-12-22 13:22:46.208 Menu-Desk[4102:160194] AddingMenuData AYRAN
2014-12-22 13:22:46.208 Menu-Desk[4102:160194] AddingMenuData Türk Kahvesi
2014-12-22 13:22:46.209 Menu-Desk[4102:160194] AddingMenuData ÇAY
2014-12-22 13:22:46.209 Menu-Desk[4102:160194] Adding icecekData SU
2014-12-22 13:22:46.209 Menu-Desk[4102:160194] Adding icecekData KOLA
2014-12-22 13:22:46.210 Menu-Desk[4102:160194] self.Data count: 3
2014-12-22 13:22:46.446 Menu-Desk[4102:160194] Name  : AYRAN 
2014-12-22 13:22:46.447 Menu-Desk[4102:160194] Name  : Türk Kahvesi

Comment: Why are you not using ARC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     if(tableView.tag==1001)
     {
         NSLog(@"self.Data count: %lu", (unsigned long)[menuData count]);
         return [menuData count];
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"self.İçkiler: %lu", (unsigned long)[icecekData count]);
         return [icecekData count];
     }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellidentifier=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier];
    }
    if (tableView.tag==1001)
    {
        veriler=[menuData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        NSLog(@"Name  : %@ ", veriler.menuadi);
        cellValue= veriler.menuadi;
    }
    if (tableView.tag==2002)
    {
        veriler=[icecekData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        NSLog(@"Name  : %@ ", veriler.icecek);
        cellValue= veriler.icecek;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=cellValue;
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}

// Edited
 - (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    menuData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [menuData retain];

    icecekData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [icecekData retain];
    [self callwebservice];

    [itablo reloadData];
    [mtablo reloadData];
 }
// Please check the Delegate and Datasource setting for both TableView
```

Comment: This my  LOG :icecekData count not return.   2014-12-22 12:47:05.045 Menu-Desk[3767:149544] self.Data count: 3
2014-12-22 12:47:05.046 Menu-Desk[3767:149544] Name  : AYRAN 
2014-12-22 12:47:05.047 Menu-Desk[3767:149544] Name  : Türk Kahvesi (Orta) 
2014-12-22 12:47:05.048 Menu-Desk[3767:149544] Name  : ÇAY  (Bardak)

Comment: Check icecekData is null or not.

Comment: icecekdata is not null. I am logging it. but it is not return after  return [menuData count];

Comment: Okay got it. After first tableView loaded, just call [SecondTableView reloadData];

Comment: Can u write me code. I try after  veriler=[menuData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        NSLog(@"Name  : %@ ", veriler.menuadi);
        cellValue= veriler.menuadi; it is error.

Comment: Please post your full code from where you create your two table. otherwise I'm unable to understand your problem.

Comment: I send It. Thanks. I am waiting your helps. @Monikanta

Comment: @HakanOZGUR,,I have edited my answer. Check it once and First make sure that the Delegate and Datasource connection for Both TableView is correct.

Comment: I checked my Delegate and Datasource connection. This is piccure for them http://i.stack.imgur.com/92rNM.jpg. IO try your editing answer but itablo is still nil. :(

Answer (score 0):

In your else statement of `numberOfRowsInSection`, make sure to wrap it in { }.  Only the NSLog is conditionally run, while `return [icecekData count]` is always being run, unconditionally.
Should look like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(tableView.tag==1001)
    {
        NSLog(@"self.Data count: %lu", (unsigned long)[menuData count]);
        return [menuData count];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"self.İçkiler: %lu", (unsigned long)[icecekData count]);
        return [icecekData count];
    }
}
```

Comment: Also check if icecekData is having some values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check basic things also like, if you have connected the outlets correct in Xib for 2nd table view, also check if delegate and datasource methods are connected. And if all right also check the tag value if you have set it correct to 2002 tableview.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved Problem. Thanks @Monikanta you are right. i use `[self.itable reloadData]` but not in method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

.Because i am called web service. My Code is Now  :

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection {


NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];




[theXML release];

if (xmlParser)
{
    [xmlParser release];
}
xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData];
[xmlParser setDelegate: self];

[xmlParser parse];
[self.mtablo reloadData];
[self.itablo reloadData];
[connection release];
[webData release];
}
```

Before editing is :

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection {


NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];




[theXML release];

if (xmlParser)
{
    [xmlParser release];
}
xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData];
[xmlParser setDelegate: self];

[xmlParser parse];
[self.mtablo reloadData]; // I ADD  [self.itablo reloadData];
[connection release];
[webData release];
}
```